# cloud composer spark submit existing Hadoop cluster

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to use cloud composer at few days
But, I has a mission that spark submit to our existing Hadoop cluster with yarn mode

Is it possible using by cloud composer?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that can be done by Apache Airflow 1.9.0 can be done by Cloud Composer currently. In this case, maybe take a look at the [SparkSubmitOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py) ?

Comment: Hi Mittens thank for reply. I knew SparkSubmitOperator. but I think that spark submit on yarn operation available airflow worker inside yarn cluster server. but cloud composer was not accessing our yarn cluster using by SparkSubmitOperator